# What is the formula to slice a nested loop in threads evenly?

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, nested, complexity-theory

Having a dataset, where each row needs to apply a weighing function in combination with each other row (cross join). Whether the function is applied depends on the data in both rows, so I can't just use a database.

Therefore, a solution is implemented in python. For a performance boost, threading is to be applied.

The question is now, what is the formula to split the dataset in evenly spreaded iterations, so each thread has nearly the same work.

A simplified version of the code is stated below.

```
l = 250000  # number of rows
N = 8       # number of threads
for threadid in range(N):
    kstart = ### WHAT IS THE FORMULA TO GIVE EACH THREAD THE SAME WORK
             ### i.e. the starting index of the next thread begins after the last row of the previous thread
    klen =
    # Start thread here
    #threading.Tread(..., (kstart,klen))

def _threaded(kstart, klen):
    for k1 in range(kstart, klen):
        for k2 in range(k1, l - k1):
            # DoSomething(k1, k2)
            pass
```

Example:

The loop shown above results in this iterations:

```
k1     | k2
0      | 0 to 249999 = 250000 iterations in inner loop
1      | 1 to 249999 = 249999 iterations in inner loop
2      | 2 to 249999 = 249998 iterations in inner loop
...
249999 | 249999 = 1 iteration in inner loop
```

- A simple version of kstart could be: 'l // N * threadid' - this spreads the whole set in evenly distributed groups.

Thread 1: 0 - 31249

Thread 2: 31250 - 62499

...

Thread 8: 218750 - 249999

- Now we let k1 loop over kstart until kstart of the next batch.
- Problem is now, for small k1, k2 has to do a lot of work. For big k1, the work is nearly zero.

How to slice the batches for k1 better, so that?

Thread 1: 0 - 10

Thread 2: 11 - 100

Thread 3: 101 - 500

Thread 8: 128000 - 250000

(this is an example, the numbers aren't correct)

Comment: The `grouper()` recipe in the [Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) section of the documentation may do what you want,

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Grouper seems to create fixed length chunks. Because of 'k2 in range (k1, l-k1)', the threads would not get fairly distributed work. (thread 1 would work 15 minutes, while thread 8 is done in 1 second)

Comment: Hmm, guess I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. I suggest that you [edit] your question and put in an example of what you would like the slicing to produce to make things clearer. In other words what you mean by "GIVE EACH THREAD THE SAME WORK".

Comment: Added a step by step example and rephrased the question. Hopefully it helps to understand, what I mean.

Comment: That helps a little. In what way is batching a certain way "better" than another? What determines this and how can it be calculated in advance? What is needed is some kind of concrete definition of "optimal batching". Since you want each thread/batch to have the "SAME WORK", how exactly is the amount of work being measured?